# 1970s short story about lone explorer on spaceship learning dark secret about his mission

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-exploration

I think I read this one in a early 1970s era "Best of" anthology. It's about a man who was sent from earth on a spaceship, without any companion but the ship's computer. As he approaches death from old age, he learns that the computer has kept a secret - the reason humans are sent on these missions is to determine in a strictly experimental way, how far a ship with a living human can go from Earth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it - it's "[Evane](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44506)" by E. C. Tubb, which I read in *[The 1974 Annual World's Best SF](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?34900)*

**It's about a man who was sent from earth on a spaceship, without any companion but the ship's computer.**

"Evane" is the name of the ship's computer.

**As he approaches death from old age, he learns that the computer has kept a secret - the reason humans are sent on these missions is to determine in a strictly experimental way, how far a ship with a living human can go from Earth.**

"When you cease to function, Charles, we will have reached terminal distance from the home world. I shall then reverse direction and commence to search for a suitable world to receive our cargo."